# How to accurately divide by integers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, division

I want a JavaScript function that reduces an array of numbers to an average of those numbers. My function code looks like this:

```
Array.prototype.avg = function(ignoreZero = false) {
    return (this.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }) / (this.length));
};
```

But I know that this might result in inaccurate values for rational numbers with decimal points due to the way numbers are handled in JavaScript, and so the average may be inaccurate.

I'm not exactly clear on the details as to why this problem exists (I don't really understand floating point), but I would like to know if there is an easy solution to this.

It seems like most people just recommend multiplying the decimal component away from rational numbers, but since I don't ever know how many decimals a rational number may have, this solution won't work.

Comment: Given numbers `[2, 3, 5]` what average value would you expect?

Comment: You can't have infinite precission with finite memory (and finite time), unless you decide to handle the computation in an abstract way (like wolfram alpha or math calculators). What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: you can try multiplying the decimal to an integer, so let's say 0.001 you do * 1000 and then do your calculations with it.

Comment: @OrryVandermeulen Non float values are also not precise in javascript.

Comment: ah thanks. I'd like accuracy to 2 decimal places

Comment: What is the meaning of Array, prototypes, reduce function, Etc., regarding to your question's title?

Comment: The sum of the array values is calculated via reduction. The function is just added to Array's prototype because in this specific case it is convenient to call this way. @Ele. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @GiulioBambini - if I multiple the sum of the array by 1000, and then divide by the length of the array, and then divide by 1000, will that give me accurate results?

Comment: @ZachSmith I understand that, however, you could ask in a different way without all of that code imho.

Comment: @ZachSmith The problem isn't with just decimal places. This stuff has been already covered on So multiple times. I recommend this: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1):

The js community has a solution for every inherent feature of javascript so...   Bam there's a library for that.

http://mathjs.org/docs/getting_started.html

Specifically big numbers
http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/bignumbers.html

Comment: This library still gives me 0.1+0.2 = 0.00000004

Comment: Are you using bignumbers?

Comment: no - i tried this library and it works though: https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/

Comment: Or you use fraction.js - a rational number library, also used by math.js: https://github.com/infusion/Fraction.js